# Two libraries extend EAGLview and I want to use them both. How?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone, openframeworks, eaglview

[openFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc) and [cocos2d](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) both have a wrapper for `EAGLview.h`, and of course you can't just use both. Just adding both libraries (`libcocos2d.a` and `libofxiPhone_iphoneos_Release.a`) to my project gives a linker error:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_ES1Renderer in /Developer/of_007_iphone/apps/cwi007/iTicTacToe/libofxiPhone_iphoneos_Release.a(ES1Renderer.o) and /Developer/of_007_iphone/apps/cwi007/iTicTacToe/libs/libcocos2d.a(ES1Renderer.o) for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

I'm writing the core of my program in **openFrameworks** because it's easy and C++. I want to put a UI, transitions, menus etc. in with **cocos2d** because it's also easy and looks nice.

I tried

```
#define __OPENFRAMEWORKS__
```

in one `.h` file, and wrapping the other in

```
#ifndef __OPENFRAMEWORKS__
#endif
```

figuring I could "augment" the `.h` in openFrameworks with the extra bits added in by cocos2d, but then openFrameworks wouldn't build because it no longer had a definition for `EAGLview`.

Is there a best practice for working with two libraries like this that both tap into the same low-level functionality, in this case `CoreAnimation`? Can I write my own class that inherits from them both? Is there a way to excise one of the `.h` files from my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to include the `cocos2d.h` header where `EAGLview.h` is included in the original openFrameworks code (i.e. `ofMain.h`), or vice versa.

Comment: Noted in OP that just having both libs in the project causes a linker error because of symbol duplication.

Comment: But... yes! Rebuilding the libs appropriately does it.